# Javascript: Upload HTML to S3

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I need to upload some HTML content to my backend (which then saves it as an HTML file on AWS S3).

I have created the `document` object, using [`document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument). Now I need to send it to my backend (I am using Backand backend-as-a-service) and [its integration with S3](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/scenarios/amazon/index.html) to save the data as an HTML file in an S3 bucket, but I am struggling with that process.

I reckon this is what I need to do (please correct me if I'm wrong or there is a simpler way):

1. Convert the `document` object to a string (the file contents including the `<!doctype HTML>` declaration) - using `htmlString = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' + document.documentElement.outerHTML;`
2. Convert the string to a Blob - using `new Blob([htmlString], 'text/html');` **Or can I / should I just send it as a string?**
3. http the Blob to the backend.
4. Convert it back to a HTML string?
5. Upload it to the S3 bucket.

Any pointers in the right direction much appreciated!

Comment: I would say go for blob or just plain string, base64 is more overhead and ~3x larger

Answer (score 1):

For future readers... after some playing around, it wasn't too hard:

1. Convert `document` to an HTML string (As above)
2. Encode it as base-64 using `window.btoa()` (no need for blobs)
3. http to the backend
4. The backend uploads to S3 (no need to decode)

:-)

Here's (something like) the code I ended up with:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('Document Title');
  //  ... Do stuff to the document ...
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' + doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
var filedata = window.btoa(html);

// http call to my server (Backand) using Angular $http

$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/action/<objectname>/name=uploadToS3',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   data: {
      'filename': 'folder/filename.html',
      'filedata': filedata
   }
}).then( .... ); // etc.
```